# How to read usage_timestamp

Tags: javascript, ios

I need help read these usage_timestamp please, 13281776741000000
13236152973000000

I reallt want to know from what application those usahe_timestamp, please anyone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why [ios] tag? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), thank you

Answer (score 0):

To read the timestamp, just use the Date API.

```js
console.log(Date(13281776741000000));

// returns "Fri May 05 2023 11:33:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)";

console.log(Date(13236152973000000))

//returns Fri May 05 2023 11:34:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```